# Syntax error in yaml lib after updating google-cloud-sdk

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

After running: `sudo apt-get upgrade` I got:

> Setting up google-cloud-sdk (274.0.1-0) ... Compiling
>
> platform/bq/third_party/yaml/lib3/**init**.py ...   File
>   "platform/bq/third_party/yaml/lib3/**init**.py", line 284
>       class YAMLObject(metaclass=YAMLObjectMetaclass):
>                                 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...

I have Debian GNU/Linux 10

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on the new version of the SDK.

It is already being tracked by the Google Engineering Team on the issue tracker on this link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146447037